# Which layouts to use when building an app launcher application?

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android development and right now I've to build an app that works like an app launcher where it displays authorized apps set by the user.

It should look like something like this:

[App launcher design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr0Kg.png)

From what I've been looking into it, should be a tab layout with a Viewpager and a gridview?

Is there any example available? I've found very little online about this, so any tutorial that you know of would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Gridview

Comment: And go through this https://www-androidhive-info.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCKAE%3D#aoh=15746227310312&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2016%2F05%2Fandroid-build-intro-slider-app%2F

Comment: Launcher is just another application, you can use any layout that suites your needs.